# Upgrade old cordova phone gap project to ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, keystore, phonegap

I have an old cordova project that i created a few years back (2014) and now the Play Store is asking me to update my cordova version to 4.1.1 +.

and since the project is too old i decided to switch to ionic, i created my new app and now i am stack trying to get it to the Play Store, when i upload my signed apk file i get a warning saying that i have to use my old signing key store, the problem is that i don't remember creating one in the past and i couldn't find any key store in my old app.

my old cordova version was 3.6.x

Comment: If you don't have the keystore then you will have to release it as a new app, there is no other way

Comment: i don't remember creating one! does Play Store use the key store since they lunched ?

Comment: yeah, I submitted my first app like 7 years ago and I had to create it